# Issue with webview and scrollview

Tags: android, webview, scroll, scrollview

I can't resolve my problem with scrollView and webView,
I know, that i can't put webview into scrollview but I have't idea how to jump it.
In my scrollView, I have image ( 1280 x 1300 > ) and this image must be scrolling, under image i must have webview with html content. have you any idea how should I do that?

is any another way to put html content with  to some view?

this is my xml view, and I add image and webview in my activity class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainLinear"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_journal_page"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ScrollView>

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#d5d5d3" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i create view somethink like that:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Journal.this, R.anim.fade_in);

        relativeLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(WIDTH, result.getHeight() + HEIGHT));
        relativeLayout.setOrientation(1);
        coverImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        coverImage.setImageBitmap(result);

        relativeLayout.addView(coverImage);
        Integer pageNumber = Integer.valueOf(ArrayHelper.journalList.get(pageIdentity).get("pageId").toString());
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MCW/"+ pageNumber +"/content.html");
        if(file.exists()) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            WebView wV = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                InputStream fin = null;
                int len;
                fin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
                len = fin.read(buffer);
                fin.close();
                String rawText = EncodingUtils.getString(buffer, 0, len, "utf-8");
                wV.loadDataWithBaseURL("", rawText, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            }catch (Exception e) {}
            linearLayout.addView(wV);
            relativeLayout.addView(linearLayout);
        }
        scrollview.addView(relativeLayout);
        scrollview.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
        isReadyToChange = true;
    }
```

Comment: may I ask again why do you need a scroll view and not just an Image view with layout_height="wrap_content" and your web view below it ???

Comment: because, i have an image higher then screen, and i should scroll it ;)

Comment: I think that what I mentioned does what you want.

Comment: could you write some example xml ?

Comment: @Dawid, have you succeeded ? I have almost similar problem.

Comment: @Kaillash i didn't resolved my problem. What kind of problem you have ?

Comment: @Dawid, when I put web view, inside a scroll view, then some times web view stops responding to touch events. After some modification in the layout, I am able to resolve it, but I had to compromise with some other feature(s). In brief, web view inside a scroll view does not seem reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Scrollview with Height FillParent
add a linearlayout height= deviceHeight+imageHeight

use a linearlayout with height of device
add webview to this linearlayout 
add image and linearlayout  to this layout

Comment: i can't add webview into scrollview ;/

Comment: i do something like this, create linearLayout -> create imageView -> add imageView to linearLayout -> create webView -> add webView to linear layout -> add linearLayout to scrollView. But this couldn't work.

Comment: There is only one solution possible to your problem which is use a scroll layout is parent to all childs, which you want to be visible, but as you can not add a webview to scrollview, add webview to linearlayout before adding to parent layout, whole layout architecture would be <scroll_View> <LinearLayout Height=image+screen><ImageView/><LinearLayout height=screen><webview/></LinearLayout></LinearLayout></ScrollView>

Comment: what are you getting, on screen, can you specify

Comment: Firstly, when my content in webview is heighter than screen a cant scroll it, secondly when my content in webview is smaller than screen i have strange blinking, thirdly i have ontouchlistner on my scrollview, and when i scroll to webview ontouch doesn't work ;/

Comment: on touch wont work on webview because webview override the touch event, then you are having some webview issue, you need to assign height param to webview wrap_content, and then see

Comment: i must have ontouch event on webview, should i override this event ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6891/discussion-between-jitendra-sharma-and-dawid-sajdak)

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/pho"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dd1"/>

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this would meet your requirement or not, however

> ```
> is any another way to put html content with to some view ?
> ```

You can use `TextView` to display `HTML` content

`mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml('html_content'));`

Also go through [Mark Murphy - HTML Tags Supported By TextView](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

As a side note, HTML may also be used as a string resource, as described [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Comment: I know, that I can put html string to TextView, bu I can't put <style></style> code to TextView, and this is a problem.